# Element X in the DataSet references an object missing from the Database

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

When first time I created my App, I created a Database using Microsoft SQL SERVER Management Studio and I connected my App with it.

I created another DB with the same tables and every thing but with diferent names and I let my App to connect to the second one because I want to make some changes and when I am trying to edit my DataSet with Wizard I get this tables page :

[image]

as you can see my app couldn't find the right tables and when I am trying to select LastWork table as in the pic, it will make the table name in the DataSet LastWork1.

How I can fix this problem? and let it find the right tables

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem when using copies of databases as well, after pointing to a different connection in the settings area of the project properties. The XSD evidently hard codes each DbObjectName with the name of the database and schema in use at design time. One approach to fixing it is to open the wizard for the appropriate dataset, uncheck the red-x objects with the missing references, close the wizard, then re-open it and re-select the objects that are needed. This is not ideal in a large xsd if many findby queries, custom columns, etc. have been added. So an alternative is to do a find and replace on the database name within the XSD itself.

Interestingly, my experience has been that an application runs fine when the connection string points to a differently named but otherwise identical database.